# oracle Sql nvl or case which one is faster?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, query-optimization, nvl

I want to talk about a scenario that we can use both nvl or case in the select statement.
In PL-SQL using nvl will be easier that is true. But when it comes to query (in select statement)

will using nvl make it slower? I have a package that have loads of select statement with NVl. If I replace them  with case will it work faster?

For example;

```
select  case sum(nvl(birikim,0)) when null then 0 else sum(nvl(birikim,0) end
```

instead of using this,

```
select nvl(sum(nvl(birikim, 0)), 0))
```

Comment: `nvl(sum(birikim), 0)` is enough and test it.

Comment: Optimizing of the built-in function invocation is the last step you need to worry about. Is your query fast enough to see the difference? Is it processing single record? For test purpose you may spend some time to prepare appropriate setup with cold starts, buffer flush, multiple runs etc and compare plain select with no function at all and the same query with, for example, NVL. I bet timings will be statistically insignificant and impacted mostly by network and disk IO

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will see a great performance increase. Built in functions are very optimized. On the other hand, any function that you use on `SELECT` statement will have impact in performance, unless your indexes take the function in consideration.

My suggestion: run an `EXPLAIN PLAN` on both queries to check the performance.

If there is not that much difference, take readability into consideration. Having `NVL` instead of `CASE` will make it more readable. Sometimes you have to balance performance with maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are looking for a micro-optimization.  The expense of a SQL query is usually in the data movement, not in the particular actions taken on the data within one row (unless you are working with large string or blobs or user-defined functions or something like that).

Second, running a function *inside* the `SUM()` is going to incur overhead for every row.  That said, you may not be able to measure the effect unless you are measuring on a very large table.

Third, you don't need to worry about `NULL` values in the `SUM()`.  So you can write your logic as:

```
select nvl(sum(birikim), 0)
```

Although I prefer `coalesce()` because it is the SQL Standard function for this purpose:

```
select coalesce(sum(birikim), 0)
```